# Detect almost grayscale image with Python

Tags: python, colors, python-imaging-library, grayscale

Inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23660929/694360) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74834150/694360) (which isn't very solid) I realized that I often find myself converting to grayscale a color image that is *almost* grayscale (usually a color scan from a grayscale original). So I wrote a function meant to measure a kind of *distance* of a color image from grayscale:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageChops, ImageOps, ImageStat

def distance_from_grey(img): # img must be a Pillow Image object in RGB mode
    img_diff=ImageChops.difference(img, ImageOps.grayscale(img).convert('RGB'))
    return np.array(img_diff.getdata()).mean()

img = Image.open('test.jpg')
print(distance_from_grey(img))
```

The number obtained is the average difference among all pixels of RGB values and their grayscale value, which will be zero for a perfect grayscale image.

What I'm asking to imaging experts is:

- is this approach valid or there are better ones?
- at which *distance* an image can be safely converted to grayscale without checking it visually?

Comment: I am not an expert. Intuitively, I would say you need to square the differences before adding them up, and then taking the square root again: Error = 1/N * sqrt(Sum error_i^2). In that case, if some pixels deviate a lot and others don't at all, this is considered worse than if every pixel deviates a little bit.

Comment: You could use a perceptually uniform colourspace, e.g. JzAzBz, ICtCp, OkLab, convert to Lightness, Chroma, Hue (LCH) representation and check whether the Chroma is close to zero.

Comment: @KelSolaar Very interesting, I'm studying your comment, I'm sure many would be grateful if you showed how to do in an answer.

Comment: Not sure exactly what cases you need to discriminate between, but you could consider the saturation in HSV colourspace as an indication of greyness https://stackoverflow.com/a/74874586/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following 3 images and using [Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour):

[image: McDonald Lake]
[image: Niagara Falls]
[image: Colourful Pencils]

```py
import numpy as np
import colour

image_1 = colour.read_image("mcdonald_lake.png")
# "mcdonald_lake.png" is single channel, we convert it to 3
image_1 = colour.utilities.tstack([image_1, image_1, image_1])
image_2 = colour.read_image("niagara_falls.png")
image_3 = colour.read_image("colouring_pencils.png")

# Converting from assumed "sRGB" encoded, i.e. "Output-Referred" to "Oklab" using Colour's Automatic Colour Conversion Graph.
image_1_OkLab = colour.convert(image_1, "Output-Referred RGB", "Oklab")
image_2_OkLab = colour.convert(image_2, "Output-Referred RGB", "Oklab")
image_3_OkLab = colour.convert(image_3, "Output-Referred RGB", "Oklab")

# Converting from "Lightness" and "a", "b" opponent colour dimensions
# to "Lightness", "Chroma" and "Hue".
image_1_OkLab_JCh = colour.models.Jab_to_JCh(image_1_OkLab)
image_2_OkLab_JCh = colour.models.Jab_to_JCh(image_2_OkLab)
image_3_OkLab_JCh = colour.models.Jab_to_JCh(image_3_OkLab)

print(np.mean(image_1_OkLab_JCh[..., 1]))
print(np.mean(image_2_OkLab_JCh[..., 1]))
print(np.mean(image_3_OkLab_JCh[..., 1]))
```

```
6.14471772026e-05
0.0292843706963
0.0798391223111
```

If you want to use `ICtCp` for example, you can simply change `"Oklab"` for `"ICtCp"` above.

It is also possible to get a detailed overview of the computations ran by the graph by using the `verbose={"mode": "Long"}` argument:

```py
colour.convert(image_1, "Output-Referred RGB", "Oklab", verbose={"mode": "Long"})
```

Google Colab Notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aDyUa4hSeCn-Sj47nUOilRAghl0fpd_W?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, that's the quality answer I was looking for, it works great, the output values differentiate *almost grey* from color images by a factor of about 4, whereas with my method the factor is about 2.5, so that's a nice improvement and I'm sure that the results are more solid.

Comment: Did something change in the last few days in the `colour` package installation with `conda install -c conda-forge colour-science` ? Arranging another environment I got an error saying the `networkx` module was missing and I had to install it manually.

Comment: Nothing from our end!

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes your grayscaling function is idempotent, if this does not hold ignore this answer entirely.

> is this approach valid

Depends on how yours inputs looks like and what you are expecting to do, consider certain edge case: you have image which consists of two parts, left half is grayscale and right half is colorful, what should happen?

> better ones?

Depends on your definition of *better*, I suggest experimenting with other function in place of `mean`, e.g. max or median.

Comment: My main purpose is detecting automatically when an image is a color scan from a grayscale original (like black and white photo or drawing), so I can convert it to grayscale without checking it visually.